# Assigning id's to button in a loop in PHP

Tags: php

I have created 5 buttons inside a while loop in PHP. But I am not able to assign ID's to them. I want to access one of the five buttons at a time using their ID when any one of them is clicked. Here's my code for this part alone:

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
        echo "<tr><td>" . 
             $row["PropertyId"] . "</td><td>" .
             $row["PropertyType"]. "</td><td>" .
             $row["PropertyName"]. "</td><td> " . 
             $row["City"]. "</td><td>" . 
             $row["AreaInSqFt"]."</td><td>".
             $row["Price"]. "</td><td>".
             "<input type = submit OnClick = submit_btn(".$i.") id = " .$i."></button>"." </tr>";           
         $i++;
    }
echo "</table>";
}

function submit_btn($id){
    echo "HEllo";
}
```

Comment: can you please format your code?? and i don't see any button here..

Comment: Your HTML in invalid. You're ending an `input` tag with a closing `button` tag and you don't have any quotes around your attribute values: `type="submit"`